# Should we try to maintain consistency in tag names?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed that there was a [past-tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-tense) tag, a [present-tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/present-tense) tag, and a [future](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future) tag. Since they are all for different tenses, it seems more reasonable to have consistent names for them. Therefore, I think that the [future-tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future-tense) tag should replace the [future](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future) tag.

Answer (score 5):

I have replaced the [future](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future) tag with the [future-tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future-tense) tag on all relevant questions.

Comment: I probably should have asked this meta question first, but I didn't think about it until it was too late. I'll try to remember next time.

Comment: I think you're pretty safe on this one, assuming all questions tagged 'future' did in fact refer to future tense. :)  Asking on meta is a good policy though! (I just wouldn't worry about it this time ^^)

Comment: Did you also make [tag:future] a synonym of [tag:future-tense]? (And ditto for [tag:past] and [tag:present], just for symmetry?)

Comment: Aside: I really, really hate the whole in-tag reputation requirements system for tag synonyms. In a subject like English or learning of same, it's really pointless. All it does is prevent me from telling the system that "yes, 'grammer' really is just a misspelling of 'grammar'".